# Local Capybara Tests with chrome on mac uses certificate to authenticate - Looking for a way to prevent this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm currently writing capybara integration tests for a rails application. Is the driver is configured like this.

```
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app,
  browser: :chrome
  desired_capabilities: capabilities,
  switches: ['--incognito']
```

The problem: During tests this chrome - even in incognito - automatically is authenticated on the website with certificates from my mac.

Is there any way to prevent the use of certificates other than deleting them? (we want to use :chrome and not :headless_chrome)

edit: found the root cause. A `com.google.Chrome.plist` file in my /Library/Preferences/ folder with some rules using automatically my company certificate for certain domains.

Comment: What options are you passing in capabilities? and what versions of Selenium, Capybara and Chrome are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the certificates are being pulled from the MacOS keychain, you can try adding the `--use-mock-keychain` switch to your driver configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found out the root cause of my issue. There was a `com.google.Chrome.plist` file in /Library/Preferences/ with some logic inside to automatically use certificates for specific domains. Removing this file solved my problem. Now I get a popup which ask the use of cert.